# Swift why use extensions when you have access to the class in the same file?

Tags: swift

So I'm learning Swift. I find it a bit confusing that a lot of tutorials seems to advocate to add extensions rather than just expand the class.

```
class ReminderListViewController: UITableViewController {

}

extension ReminderListViewController {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Reminder.testData.count
    }
}
```

Consider the code above. Why not just

```
class ReminderListViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Reminder.testData.count
    }
}
```

Comment: No particular reason.

Comment: Oftentimes it is an organizational strategy.  For example, one might put all of the table view delegate methods in one extension and layout-related code in another.

Comment: To replace pragma mark comments like `// MARK: UITableViewController methods`.

Comment: @Alexander - It generally supplements `MARK` statements (which are there largely only to provide annotations for the jump bar), not replacing them. They serve entirely different purposes.

Comment: Petro99, 1. It segregates/organizes your code into logical groupings so you can glance at your code an understand what a particular method is for. 2. It also enable code collapse (e.g. when working on `UITableViewDataSource` code, you can collapse distracting code related to other protocols). It makes it easier to work with your code.

Comment: Petro99, also see [Adding protocol conformance in an extension](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID277).

Comment: @Rob Grouping methods by which protocol they satisfy or which superclass they’re overriding from is the main purpose of `#pragma mark` in ObjC code bases that I’ve seen. Sure you can make other groupings/marks, but this is the most common one I’ve personally run into, and it largely disappeared once people adopted Swift and this grouping-by-extension convention.

Comment: @Alexander - You misunderstood me. The sole purpose of `MARK:` (as opposed to normal comment) is to annotate the jump bar. Yes, we place these `MARK:` declarations in logical places as we organize our code (e.g., esp where the purpose of the extension is unclear), but organizing the code is not the purpose of `MARK:`. It is so this organization is reflected in the jump bar. If you have extensions in a source file, and don't have `MARK:` statements, the jump bar will show you _where_ the extensions are, but not _what_ they are. In short, grouping-by-extensions does not obviate `MARK:` comments.

Comment: @Rob “ If you have extensions in a source file, and don't have MARK: statements, the jump bar will show you where the extensions are, but not what they are.” oh yeah. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually based on personal preference, some people think it looks prettier.

A different case is if a class that is being expanded depends on another class and that class needs a change to be made, then extending is much easier than your other choice; which would be expanding many classes to change one class. Sometimes this is necessary but not often.